# sharepoint 2007- Export Custom List

Tags: custom-list

How to export a sharepoint 2007 custom list from one box to other box. I tried saving as list template, but misses some of the look up columns data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to save a list template and maintain lookup relationships?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17911/possible-to-save-a-list-template-and-maintain-lookup-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

One simplistic method you might want to try is building out the target List definition with the same metadata(lookup column etc) and than copy records using datasheet view.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup columns are not carried forward from one site to another.

See this thread, [Possible to save a list template and maintain lookup relationships?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17911/possible-to-save-a-list-template-and-maintain-lookup-relationships)