# move list to a sub site with all the data

Tags: 2013, list, sub-site

I am using **SharePoint-2013**. I have three lists that I want to move to the **sub-site** with all the data.  How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can export the lists using the *SharePoint 2013 Management Shell* on a farm server with the command [**Export-SPWeb**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx), including versions and security settings if you want. Then you can import the lists in the sub-site using the command [**Import-SPWeb**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx), specifying the subsite url and the export files previously created.

You need to have **securityadmin** and **db_owner** roles on the SQL Server instance and you have to run the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell as Administrator.

After you have checked the lists in the subsite, you can delete the ones you don't need anymore.

Comment: does it keep the information of the lookup columns?

Comment: It should, if you import the list in the same site collection, because the lookup field "configuration" (lookup list + lokup field name) would be the same.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to

Save list as Template with `Content` > then at subsite create it from this template.

- Go to list Setting > Save List as a template .

[image]

- At subsite > Add app > create a list from this template

Also, you can use [Export](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428322.aspx) -and [Import](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428322.aspx)

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://site -Path c:\export.cmp -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions All -ItemUrl /lists/yourlistname

Import-SPWeb http://site/subsite –Path c:\export.cmp –UpdateVersions -Overwrite -IncludeUserSecurity
```

Comment: but the first option cannot keep the information of the lookup column.

Comment: you should  export the look up list of lookup column and reconfigure it in your subsite

Comment: that means i will lose my previous lookup fields information?

Comment: I response to your new question as a workaround solution credit for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17911/possible-to-save-a-list-template-and-maintain-lookup-relationships