# Moving list with contents from root site to sub-site does not keep the information of the lookup fields

Tags: 2013, list, lookup-column, sub-site, list-template

I have tried the following steps to move a list from root site to subsite.

- Go to list Setting > Save List as a template and include the contents
- At sub-site > Add app > create a list from this template

But in the sub-site the list does not contains the information of the lookup fields. I have created the lookup table. Is it possible to move with the lookup information?

Answer (score 2):

Credit for [Possible to save a list template and maintain lookup relationships?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17911/possible-to-save-a-list-template-and-maintain-lookup-relationships)

**Steps**

- Download the "Template.stp" file from "List Templates" after Save.
- Rename the file and change the extension of the file from ".stp" to ".cab".
- Once you have the extension as ".cab", extract the "Manifast.xml" file.
- Get the List ID of newly created .
- Replace the old value List Id in Lookup of Gender to New List ID
- After making the changes save the xml file.
  To recreate a CAB file open "Microsoft Visual Studio". Create a "CAB Project". In this case i have created "Template-Actors".(We can also use makecab.exe instead of visual studio.)
- Add the file Manifast.xml to the project.
- Build the cab project. Go to debug\bin folder you will find "Template.cab".
- Rename the file to "Template-Actors.stp".
- Upload the file to "List Template".
- Create a list using new template.
- The gender selections will now show up.